# Positioning multiple spans on top of separate divs correctly between browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having a problem with getting multiple spans to lay on top of a few divs within a WordPress post of mine correctly.

I created my own dummy webpage within Notepad++ with all the styling and things to make sure it looked how I wanted, and it looks fine. However, when I then go and put all of the HTML structure and the CSS into my WordPress site, then it doesn't look quite right.

The HTML content is the following:

```
<div class="member-status">MEMBER
    <span class="level-dot">&bull;</span>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="silver-status">
    <span class="big-checkmark">&#10004;</span>SILVER<span class="level-dot">&bull;&bull;</span>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="gold-status">GOLD
    <span class="level-dot">&bull;&bull;&bull;</span>
</div>
```

And the CSS to back it is this:

```
.member-status {
position:relative;
width:200px;
color:#fff;
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #5cadff;
text-align:center;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #5cadff;
padding:20px 30px;

background:#1874cd;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4f9eea, #1874cd);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#4f9eea, #1874cd);
background-image: linear-gradient(#4f9eea, #1874cd);

-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
}

.silver-status {
position:relative;
width:200px;
color:#555;
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #bbb;
text-align:center;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #bbb;
padding:20px 30px;

background:#c0c0c0;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eaeaea, #c0c0c0);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#eaeaea, #c0c0c0);
background-image: linear-gradient(#eaeaea, #c0c0c0);

-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
}

.gold-status {
position:relative;
width:200px;
color:#e68a00;
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #ffff80;
text-align:center;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #ffff80;
padding:20px 30px;

background:#ffd700;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff2aa, #ffd700);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff2aa, #ffd700);
background-image: linear-gradient(#fff2aa, #ffd700);

-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
}

.big-checkmark {
position:absolute;
top:7px;
left:12px;
color:#3c3;
font-size:2.5em;
}

.level-dot {
position:absolute;
top:7px;
right:15px;
font-size:2.5em;
}
```

You can see the end result on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WcQbL/1/

Here's the thing... on Chrome this looks perfect to me. The big-checkmark and level-dot spans look perfectly placed where I want them.

In Firefox and IE11, the level-dots look like they are positioned well, but the big-checkmark is positioned way down from the center on Firefox, and slightly down from center on IE11. I am pushing both the spans down the exact same way using top:7px;

Now... I went and plugged in this same HTML structure into a test post of mine on WordPress, and I added all the appropriate CSS to my child theme's style.css file.

However, when I go to the post, both the level-dots and the big-checkmark are positioned way up high on all 3 of the divs and it looks really bad.

So, my question is... is there a better way I can go about positioning these spans on top of these divs so that it is consistent among all browsers? And is there maybe some CSS in my parent style.css that would be affecting the spans being way up high once I plug the SAME exact code into my WordPress post?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first time working with spans on top of divs, so I apologize if the CSS code is not-so-great.

One more note, I originally had posted this on the "WordPress Development" Stack Exchange, but they told me to come here. I feel like it may just be purely a markup issue that will get it to work on all browsers including my Wordpress site, but maybe it is WordPress specific.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem. In the old code, I was letting the padding on my divs more or less do the "sizing" of the div for me and give it the look that I wanted. In the old code, I had only specified a width on my divs, no height.

In the fix, I specified my own height and width (width:275px and height:70px). Then, in order to get text or other things to center correctly within a div you should specify the "line-height" property as well so I set line-height:70px to match my regular height. Then, took all of the padding out (padding:0).

As a specific example, the "member-status" class now looks like this:

```
.member-status {
    position:relative;
    height:70px;
    line-height:70px;
    width:275px;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #5cadff;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #5cadff;
    padding: 0;

    background:#1874cd;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4f9eea, #1874cd);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#4f9eea, #1874cd);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4f9eea, #1874cd);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #777;
}
```

Lastly, I was forcing the "big checkmark" and "level-dot" to be in a specific position. I took the "top:7px" property out because that was pushing it down too far now with my changes, but left the "left" and "right" properties on there to get them spaced away from the left and right borders where I wanted them.

You can see the new code at: [New fixed way](http://jsfiddle.net/WcQbL/2/)

And the old code at: [Old wrong way](http://jsfiddle.net/WcQbL/1/)

If you look at the new code in all the different browsers, it looks the exact same now and exactly how I want it -- no differences between each browser.

Hope this helps someone!